What is the latest version of the VC Redistributables merge modules? Where to get them?
We are using Visual Studio 2022, installing the workload Desktop development with C++.
Sadly, this does not seems to provide the MSVC Redist merge modules (.msm files) anymore.
The question this raises is twofold:

What is the current latest version of those merge modules?
Where can specific version of the merge modules (including the latest) be downloaded? More specifically, we need to retrieve VC143 merge modules.


For reference, in addition to installing the default components of the Desktop development with C++ workload, we tried the following components:

Windows 10 SDK: no effect
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 build tools: this added an entry 14.29.30133 under VC/Redist/MSVC, but without any MergeModule folder.
MSVC v141 - VS 2017 build tools: this added an entry 14.16.27012 under VC/Redist/MSVC, which does contain a MergeModules folder, only containing msm files for VC141.


It seems the MSM cannot be installed via workloads anymore (except for MSVC v141 build tools).
They can be installed by going to the Individual components tab, then searching "msm" in the search. This brings up C++ 2022 Redistributables MSMs component.
Installing this component has added a MergeModules subfolder to each version folder present in VC/Redist/MSVC. From browsing the latest version, it seems that the latest version of the redistributable merge modules is VC143.
